# How to get only the first 5 contents between the same tags?

Tags: regex

```
<a href="http://example.com/">what I want</a>
```

I want to get text between `/">(.*?)< / a>`. But there are nearly 20 tags like that, and I only want to get the first 5 of those.

I did something like `^(/">(.*?)< / a>){5}` but it didn't work.

I'm using Tasker.

Comment: Instead use a parser and some xpath queries.

Comment: Also, are you sure about the _caret_? You're anchoring the thing to the start of the line.

Comment: I'm not sure about any of. i don't have sufficient knowledge about regex. I read lots of posts and formed this exampe.

Answer (score 0):

With any shell, you use `head -5` to get the 1st 5 lines and then use sed to get what you want: `file_name` being the file containing these `html` tags:

```
head -5 file_name | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```